# Using Progressbar in c# windows application

Tags: c#

The user will be able to search for some document in the local machine and i want to show user, a progress bar during my program searches. To be more clear, i have foreach loop for which i want to tie up my progress bar to show the progress. my foreach loop and progress should work simultaneously.  Is this possible to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [ProgressBar Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx)

You can try something like

```
private void CopyWithProgress(string[] filenames)
{
    // Display the ProgressBar control.
    pBar1.Visible = true;
    // Set Minimum to 1 to represent the first file being copied.
    pBar1.Minimum = 1;
    // Set Maximum to the total number of files to copy.
    pBar1.Maximum = filenames.Length;
    // Set the initial value of the ProgressBar.
    pBar1.Value = 1;
    // Set the Step property to a value of 1 to represent each file being copied.
    pBar1.Step = 1;

    // Loop through all files to copy.
    for (int x = 1; x <= filenames.Length; x++)
    {
        // Copy the file and increment the ProgressBar if successful.
        if(CopyFile(filenames[x-1]) == true)
        {
            // Perform the increment on the ProgressBar.
            pBar1.PerformStep();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For longer running task, you might also consider using [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: @astander, thanks for your code. It helped me a lot. I am using this code inside a button click event. The progress bar is not working in the runtime.